# How to Exclude Directories from Rules in Web.config (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have these rules set in my Web.config:

```xml
    <rules>
        <rule name="replacedash">
          <match url="(.*)(-)(.*)\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
              <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
            <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
```

I've upgraded my website from plain ASP.NET to ASP.NET MVC and I've written these rules just in case there are still some old cached links in search engines with .aspx extensions; however, there are some directories on my web server that still contain .aspx files for good reasons and my rules are rewriting those extensions as well.

How do I exclude these folders from inheriting my rules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the following solution here:

[How to exclude a directory with IIS URL rewriting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708765/how-to-exclude-a-directory-with-iis-url-rewriting)

You could do something like this:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="ignore web forms folder 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^webformsfolder1/" />
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="ignore web forms folder 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^webformsfolder2/" />
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="ignore web forms folder 3" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^webformsfolder3/" />
        <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="replacedash">
      <match url="(.*)(-)(.*)\.aspx$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
        <match url=".*" negate="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: can you help me? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067459/htaccess-to-web-config-iis-issues-route