# .htaccess to web.config iis issues route

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, web.config-transform

Good night. I have a site in `php/apache` and the file of configurations of routes is the `.htaccess`. I need pass the site to `azure` plataform `web.config` But, I can not work the routes in the IIS. I did a schematic of how the site works.

[image]

I want to hide the .php extension and make the route work 100%. The url `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/notify/f/43` has 2 variables: `f` and `43`.

My first `.htaccess` file from the `\wwwroot\site` directory and my second `.htaccess` file from `folder_1` directory is: (they are the same)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# If a script is called without .php extension, but with /variables
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\\._-]*)?/(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [QSA,E=PATH_INFO:/$2,L]

# If a script is called without .php extension, and without /variables
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

# Fix PHP Authentication with FastCGI mode
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !''
RewriteRule .*php - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you very much for the attention. I look forward to having some response. =)

Comment: Are you using PHP on Azure like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-php

Comment: Also, does your app have a web.config yet? If so, please post. Here is an example that handles `index.php` but needs rewrite rules added to handle the`/notify...` route.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SyntaxC4/3139686#file-web-config

Comment: @dana I am using php on azure yes! My application has a file 'web.config'. But I can't make it he work! In apache the script it works 100%. E need change to web.config

Comment: @dana this web.config --> https://pastebin.com/VfnKKtGg work in my case in the route `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/notify/f/43` but for `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/folder_1` not show index.php

Comment: @dana and still with this config https://pastebin.com/VfnKKtGg. Displays site but with `Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/notify/f/43`

Comment: I don't have access to a PC right now, so my help is pretty limited :) But I think the "sans php" rule and default document are fighting. I would remove the "sans php" rule and use the default document from the GIST that I linked you too.

Comment: @dana You would be the only one who could help me .. I did what you said. I removed the 'sans php' rule and I put the default GIST document and I still did not succeed = /