# URL Rewrite Loop in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a very simple URL Rewrite redirect rule that results in an infinite loop. When it fails a "Can't display page" error is displayed.  Any error trapping tips or script modifications would be appreciated.

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Test redirect" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/pub/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.*(com|net)$" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

- The rule is located in the wwwroot folder web.config file.
- The rule redirects to an MVC application in the wwwroot/pub/ folder.
- The IIS log is showing that the /pub/ folder is being called multiple times in the loop until the request is terminated by IIS.
- If the rule is disabled and I enter the URL directly it works fine.
- The same error is seen on different browsers.
- It is not a browser cache issue.

Comment: Could you paste your URL Rewrite rule here?

Comment: For some strange reason stackoverflow isn't allowing me to paste the rule in the question.  Maybe it's the bullet points.  I'll paste it below.

Comment: <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Test redirect" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
         <action type="Redirect" url="/pub/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.*(com|net)$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I'm going to try pasting it before the bullet points to see if that works.

Comment: Yes, it works prior to the bullet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to SSL.  An HTTPS redirect requires an {HTTPS} condition, as shown below. Without that condition the rule will loop when you attempt to redirect to an https:\ URL. You also must include the entire https:\ URL in the action as shown.

```
<rule name="Test redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://yourdomain.com/pub/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Temporary" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain.*(com|net)$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your URL Redirect rule is being hit multiple times, since it's matching on all URLs via the `<match url=".*" />` directive. [This post says that](https://forums.iis.net/t/1173355.aspx) the `stopProcessing='true'` directive doesn't necessarily work for Redirect rules.

[Taking a look at a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770648/866021), you might want to add a `block` rule first in order to prevent any URLs with the fragment `mydomain.com/pub` from triggering any rewrite rules and entering your infinite loop scenario:

```
<rule name="block" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^mydomain.*(com|net)/pub.*" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks Adil, but it's still looping.  I can do a redirect using rules with a web.config file located in the web application folder.  But it seems to fail when the rule is applied to the web.config in the wwwroot folder.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

can you review your code and all paths should be absolutes, for example... the scripts

js/jquery.js is a bad path. Correct path is /js/jquery.js